# An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host - Even with TLS1.2

Tags: c#, sharepoint, tls1.2, windows-server-2012-r2

Recently our Sharepoint Integration stopped working and all we receive is the error in the title. I have read all threads and articles I could find and it all points towards TLS-version. The same software is running fine on 2 of our machines in the office, so it has to do with the environment.
I have done the following:

1. Disabled TLS1.0, TLS1.1 in Registry
2. Force use TLS 1.2 by setting ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
3. Site running ASP.NET 4.8
4. Ensured only TLS version is enabled is 1.2 according to SSLLabs.com
5. According to Microsoft documentation, AES256 is required, and is enabled, and confirmed via SslLabs

What am I missing here?

Comment: you can download WireShark, and capture tcp package, and then anylize closed reason.

Comment: Even if you have TLS12 enabled, you may be missing required Cipher Suites (or some are disabled in the configuration). You should mention the System version where the issue is generated. Check with [IIS Crypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/) (free software). SHA (`SHA1`) must be enabled.

Comment: The error is due to a connection not completing which occurs before TLS is run.  So it is not a TLS issue.  There are four reasons I've seen for this error 1) The server is not running 2) The client and server are not using the same port number 3) The  port number is already being used 4) The client code is trying to connect to the loopback address 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I will for sure download Wireshark, good thinking! I have updated the answer with regards to the Cipher Suits.

Comment: JDWeng - 1. Server is for sure running, accessing with same code from other machine is working great. 2. We do not set any port, we are using NuGet-package from Micrsoft for integration with Office365. 3. Not sure how this can happen all the sudden 4. Client code, in Office365 is probably not connecting to loopback address

Comment: There are different version of AES256. Check here what's available in Windows Server 2012R2 (and what's not enabled by default): [TLS Cipher Suites in Windows 8.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-8-1) and what the TLS handshake is demanding (IIRC, the last update related to Cipher Suites for 2012R2 was in 2014). If you plan on using WireShark or Fiddler, you'll see it clearly shown in real-time when the handshake is performed.

Comment: Checking with Wireshark we are receiving a Client Hello-message, but not Server Hello, but we are sending 11 different cipher suits, many of them corresponding to available suits in Office 365 documentation

Comment: Just found out that was not the case. I checked the Hello server-message on my development machine and the cipher there is missing on our production. Will try to install that. Thank you all

Comment: [Update adds new TLS cipher suites and changes cipher suite priorities in Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-adds-new-tls-cipher-suites-and-changes-cipher-suite-priorities-in-windows-8-1-and-windows-server-2012-r2-8e395e43-c8ef-27d8-b60c-0fc57d526d94)